# Vector recursive mean

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote this program that calculates the sum and the mean of the elements in a vector using recursive functions. The user should type as many numbers as he wants and then push "0" when finished.I ignored the  last element which would be that "0". However, something is still wrong with the sum function because it ignores the first element in the vector and therefore the mean turns out incorrect too. Here is the code:

```
    int main(void){
     vector <int> series;
     int  n;
     unsigned int nr_elem;

  cout << "Type as many numbers as you want and press 0 when you are finished:";
      do{
       cin >> n;
       series.push_back(n);
        } while (n);

  nr_elem = series.size()-1;
  cout << "nr_elem="<< nr_elem;
  cout << "\n The sum of the elements in the series is: " << sum(series, nr_elem);
  cout << "\n The average of the elements is: " << average(series, nr_elem);
  return 0;
       }

   int sum(vector<int> &series, int n){
    if (n == 0)
      return 0;
    else
      return series.at(n) + sum(series, n - 1);
    }

    double average(vector<int> &series, int n){
     if (n == 0)
     return 0;
 else
     return (series.at(n) + sum(series, n - 1)) / n;
    }
```

For the imput values:`10,20,50,0`  i get `nr_elem=3`

```
                               The sum of the elements is: 70

                               The mean is: 23`
```

This is my second trial with vectors , therefore, any explanation and additional correction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A vector's size is given by the `size()` function and it returns exactly the number of elements in the vector, but the indices are starting from zero.

You're not counting the 0 (not the terminal item you inserted, the first item of the vector!) element in your sum function

```
int sum(vector<int> &series, int n){
    if (n == 0) // This is the problem, 0 isn't the last element, is the first element!
      return 0;
    else
      return series.at(n) + sum(series, n - 1);
    }
```

To solve (minimally intrusive) change the

```
if (n == 0)
```

to something like

```
if (n == -1)
```

---

Edit: if you want to return a double value, you need to deal with double values as well. If you do your math with integers (which have NO decimal digits) you will have an integer result (with NO decimal digits). So you're losing your decimal digits.

Another "ugly" solution is to force-cast the integers into doubles and do the math when everything's double

```
double average(vector<int> &series, int n){
     if (n == -1)
     return 0;
 else
     return (static_cast<double>(series.at(n)) + static_cast<double>(sum(series, n - 1))) / static_cast<double>(n);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and now it works fine,but it still gives me an integer value for the mean even though the function should return a double.Do you happen to observe what causes that?

Comment: because your vector has integers and you are asking for a double as return value. The return value is indeed a double, but since it was an integer before.. it lost all the precision decimals. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (n == 0)
  return 0;
```

to

```
if (n == -1)
  return 0;
```

Array (vector) indices start from `0 ,1 , .... , n-1` and you returned `0` on index `0` instead of `vector[0]` .